# Чтение и запись из txt файла в сервисе

Tags: java, android

Ранее использовал этот код:

```
public void read(View vieww){
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("save.txt");
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String lines;
        while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            stringBuffer.append(lines + "\n");
        }
        FROM_N = stringBuffer.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void write(View view){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("save.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(posts.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

как вызвать его / его аналоги в service?

Comment: не совсем понимаю, в чем проблема? вроде код нормальный. И вообще что вызвать? Методы read и write?

Comment: Вся загвоздка в том, что при записи (вызове этих методов) из сервиса - крашится приложение

Comment: ну вы покажите ошибку, хотя бы первую строчку что вылетает. Скорее всего путь к файлу не верно указан. И ещё 1 совет: используйте try-with-resources или try - finally для закрытие потоков которые отработали и больше не будут вызываться.

Comment: Вот ошибка из эмулятора: 12-23 10:28:29.987 3294-3294/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system

Comment: так, ну тут все ясно. Т.к. android базируется на linux, там есть права доступа у файлов. Например в вашем случае у файлов разрешено только чтение, а нужно ещё и запись. Вызовите командную строку на вашем эмуляторе, зайдите из под root, хотя может она уже будет под root, в любом случае в конце должен стоять символ # . И введите это mount -o rw,remount /system Как в вашем эмуляторе вызвать командную строку и зайти из под root, я к сожалению не знаю. Попробуйте погуглить или посмотреть на сайте разработчика